# Is there a way to run flutter project on mobile browser?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to make a website using flutter and want to test it on a mobile browser. Is there any way to run the project on a mobile browser?

Comment: I'm not sure but try to add the flutter web address in the mobile browser and see if it works.

Comment: I tried adding the web address but the website is just frozen screen, I used firebase hosting to host my project, I was thinking I could see the error if I can try running on a mobile browser

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use your browser **Inspector** and then use toggle device toolbar to set browser size to your intended mobile size.
Or you can get web output of your website and put it on some server (like **Github-pages**) and then see your website in a real mobile browser.
But I suggest the first way more.